# How can I install the driver and make the system works on the NVIDIA GPU after tested all of the recommended driver has failed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I was using Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 Mobile on an Asus laptop.
I switch from using Window OS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS some weeks ago and I have tried to install the Nvidia Driver since then.

Here are the step I have done:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
4. reboot
   After reboot, I checked by opening the Terminal and type : nvidia-smi
   Then this senetence showed up: "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

I have tried: sudo prime-select nvidia
But the results were the same.

I have installed it several times, tried all the driver I could find in Additional Drivers but non of them changed anythings.

I don't know what is the problem I am facing here, please help me with it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled in your BIOS? Turn it off. Reboot. Retest. Report back.

Comment: I did it, then it show: "The system is running in low grpahic mode" and I cannot get back in

Comment: What version Nvidia driver? 440.64 is current for your card. Either turn Secure Boot back on, **OR** boot to Recovery Mode and reinstall the Nvidia driver, **OR** at the GRUB menu, hit "e" to enter edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 to continue booting, then reinstall Nvidia. Report back.